# How to get text from status bar in SAP GUI

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I'm tying to automate a certain process in SAP GUI. But I can't get the script this specific part.

It reads until I double click in this field shown in color green.

[image]

After that the following window is opened:

[image]

How do I get this number in VBA? Any ideas?

Comment: This is part of the [GuiStatusBar object](https://help.sap.com/docs/search?q=GuiStatusBart&product=sap_gui_for_windows) which you can obtain using `session.ActiveWindow.findById("sbar")`, and then you can use the property `Text` which contains the short text "O documento ... lançado". The documentation talks about the property `MessageParameter` but using VBScript I always get the String value "Parameter not optional." (test with SAP GUI 7.70)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know exactly what was that name but now I can look search for something. I didn't test this you mentioned because only in company I have access to SAP.

Comment: Hi, Sandra. I could get the text! Thanks!! 

Set sStatusBar = session.findById("wnd[0]/sbar")

Range("D6").Value = sStatusBar.Text

Set sStatusBar = session.findById("wnd[0]/sbar")

Comment: `session.ActiveWindow.findById("sbar")` also works, it's very useful because you don't need to worry about the window number (`0` in your case). Simplification for getting just the text: `xxxx = `session.ActiveWindow.findById("sbar").Text`.

Answer (score 3):

This should work everywhere in Excel VBA(docNumber is your result):

```
Dim objRegEx As Object
Dim theMatches As Object
Dim statusPanel As String
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
objRegEx.Global = True

objRegEx.Pattern = "[^\D]+"
statusPanel = session.FindById("wnd[0]/sbar/pane[0]").Text
Set theMatches = objRegEx.Execute(statusPanel)

For Each Match In theMatches
  docNumber = Match.Value
Next
```